# How does out-proc azure redis session get feature work?

Tags: azure, session

Scenario:
We are using azure redis session provider. When page first loads, retrieves the data from external API and stores them in redish session.

The **same** session data is retrieved via different pages and components with in user session. The question is:

1. Does application gets the session data only once and stores locally http current context? Or everytime it goes to redis store?
2. What if we are encrypting the data on set and decrypt the data on Get operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Application **gets** the session-data from Redis everytime you ask for it... for the **writing** part, you'll have to wait until the dictionary key is unlocked. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx#aspnetsessionstate_topic3 *assuming* you are using asp.net for this

> A page claims write access to the session state by setting the EnableSessionState attribute on the @Page directive to true. (This is the default setting.) A page, though, can also have read-only permissions on the session state, for example, when the EnableSessionState attribute is set to ReadOnly. In this case, the module will hold a reader lock on the session until the request for that page finishes. As a result, concurrent readings can occur.
>
> If a page request sets a reader lock, other concurrently processed requests in the same session cannot update the session state but are at least allowed to read. This means that when a session read-only request is being served, awaiting read-only requests are given higher priority than requests needing a full access. If a page request sets a writer lock on the session state, all other pages are blocked, regardless of whether they have to read or write. For example, if two frames attempt to write to Session, one of them has to wait until the other finishes.

StackExchange.Redis is just a wrapper (or a abstraction) for the HttpSessionState Module